# C# UrlReferrer from PayPal return to vendor button? Object Not Set an instance of an object

Tags: c#, object, paypal, request, referrer

After a successful Paypal transaction my customer lands on a Paypal Thank You page with a link back to my site. That link is going to the expected page.  However If I attempt to pull Referrer information from my server code,  I get error

***Object Not set to an Instance of an object.***

I have a page on the site with a link to that same page and it successfully returns the URL calling it.

I hover over the Paypal return to vendor button and it's just a link to my page.

Here's my code.

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
Response.Write(MyUrl.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
```

Could this be an issue with the page already havng been called. I've refressed the calling and destination pages. Just want to avoid re-entering CC info so I'm using the back button. Using back button and then refreshing I think should work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe PayPal has removed this HTTP header field to help improve security (they at one point populated it).  Since it can easily be rewritten/stripped, it is not a trusted indication of where the user came from.

[HTTP Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)